# ASP.NET 4.5 for Windows (without IIS)?

Tags: asp.net

Is there any portable or 3rd party software (like WampServer for PHP) to do the job of IIS (I dont want it) and run ASP.NET/MVC (latest version) on Windows 10 normally?

p.s. I have looked through similar topics, but they are 6-7 years older.

Comment: So you want to run a WebServer on Windows 10 but you do not want the built in version(IIS) instead you want a different one. Is this correct?

Comment: yes. i suppose installing the IIS service will load Win10 performance much  (with many different services and activating not-needed things).. so I'd like portable solutions, like XAMP or etc..

Comment: use ASP.NET Core with Kestrel

Comment: I've heard of Mongoose, but looks like they are having some issues with that: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629

Comment: I like Node JS.

Comment: also you can use WebListener with ASP.NET Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/weblistener

Comment: The performance concern of IIS is ridiculous. If you don't host anything on it, the impact is quite small. If you do want something like WAMP (which has bigger impact on performance) you can use IIS Express or Cassini Web Server.

Answer (score 0):

some of them I've found:

1) [Abyss Web-Server](http://aprelium.com/abyssws/)  - supports v4.5

2) [Cassini](http://ultidev.com/download/default.aspx) PRO version seems to host ASP.NET v4 (Free Version doesnt support).